# How to re-import function/variable after changing a global value in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Here's a really contrived example of what I'm trying to do. I have an immutable `value` that gets a `thing` from the window, and `value` is used inside function `example`.

**file.js**

```js
import _ from 'lodash';
const value = _.get(window, 'thing', null);

export const example = () => value;
```

I want to test `example` under different cases: when `thing` is set to `foo`, when `thing` is set to `bar`, when thing isn't set at all, etc.

I can start to set this up in a jest testing file:

**file.spec.js**

```js
import { example } from './file.js';

describe('example', () => {
  it('should return foo when window.thing is equal to foo', () => {
    window.thing = 'foo';
    const result = example();
    expect(result).toBe('foo');
  });
});
```

It looks like this would work, but it doesn't because I think when Jest sets up this testing suite, it imports the module **file.js** before I've set `window.thing` to `'foo'` in the test.

That makes sense, and I can fix this problem by declaring `thing` as pre-set global in my config:

**jest.config.js**

```js
...

globals: {
  ...

  thing: 'foo',

  ...
},

...
```

This should now make the above test pass, but there's no flexibility on being able to update `window.thing`. It looks like I would have to set `window.thing` to a different value, and then reset the module, but I don't think this will work if globals are stored in the config. If I try to add another test with a different condition:

```js
  it('should return bar when window.thing is equal to bar', () => {
    window.thing = 'bar';
    const result = example();
    expect(result).toBe('bar');
  });
```

This will fail, and it looks like there's no way for me to test `thing` with a different value within this test suite.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: You cannot use normal `import` with this. You'll want to set `window.thing`, then do a `require()` (or `import()` expression), then run your test, then clear the module cache, set `window.thing` to something else and repeat. The alternative: don't write code like that. Don't use global `const`ants that you need to change. At least put the example functionality in a separate, unit-testable module, then have the *file.js* use `import makeExample from …; export const example = makeExample(window?.thing ?? null);`

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Bergi. I have been trying to get this to work with dynamic imports at the beginning of a single unit test, but haven't figured this out yet. Still looking into it. I also will probably switch to using `const example = window?.thing ?? null` rather than the `_.get`